# VBA Combining two non-ascii languages in userform

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have userform with 2 textbox's, each textbox is for a different non-ascii language.

The user fill the textbox's and press "Submit" then in my code I generate a string of SQL query (INSERT INTO query) and send this string to SQL Server (in the SQL Server I have a "stored procedure" that continues from there, but that's not important for my question).

The thing is that I get a question marks (??????????) instead of the text that the user submitted, I can solve one language if I change the windows language for non-unicode programs, but I can select only one language there, the second language is still creates thos question marks.

Is it possible for a string variable (or any other variable) to hold a string with 2 non-ascii language's so I can send my SQL string to SQL server ?

**update:**

In the Textbox I wrote something and the text is displayed well (in the textbox), notice in the attached image that I move the cursor of the mouse on the textbox1.value, it is already displayed incorrectly, so surely later in the code when i'm concatenating it to SQL string these question marks join with the rest of the string.

[image]

Comment: Show us your SQL and the definition of your table, you're clearly using `varchar` somewhere, when you should be using `nvarchar`.

Comment: All string variables in VBA are Unicode. The Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library is also Unicode, so if you are indeed working with VBA, then both the textboxes and the string variables are Unicode, so the problem is in your code, which you should show. If you are working with VB6 though, then the textboxes there are non-Unicode.

Comment: 100% nvarchar (when I'm debuging, the string variable showing the commend - insert into... bla bla bla, and then question marks (??????)

Comment: nvarchar SQL types will allow both. Make sure your queries are properly parameterized and specify nvarchar. Literal strings need to be prefixed with `N` to denote Unicode.

Comment: @nd0911 your code is explicitly converting the strings to ASCII, one way or another. VB strings are Unicode. That's a fact. `nvarchar` is Unicode. That's another fact. You haven't posted any code, so it's impossible to say what the coding bug is. Perhaps you use dynamic SQL with ASCII strings instead of parameterized queries? Perhaps the stored data is already gone because it was stored as ASCII using the wrong codepage? Once again, due to dynamic SQL?

Comment: @nd0911 the screenshot doesn't explain anything either. VBA is ancient (it's actually VB6 from 1998) and the *debugger* probably uses the system locale to display tooltips.

Comment: Let me understand something, if a variable presents me these question marks, and I concatenate this variable with more variables to a new variable, Is the text behind these question marks "damaged" or these question marks does not say nothing about what goes on "behind the scenes" and the text still like the original ?

Comment: The question marks indicate that the string data is already damaged. At some point it tried to convert a Unicode string to either ASCII, or some specific code page, and characters that could not get converted were replaced with `?` characters. The lost characters cannot be recovered.

Comment: Are there any usages of `StrConv` in your code? That's the most common source of breakages especially if the third paramter, `LCID`, is specified.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Like Panagiotis Kanavos [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845933/vba-combining-two-non-ascii-languages-in-userform#comment116421461_65845933), it's the non-Unicode debugger that shows the `?`s. The string contents is different.

Comment: @nd0911 *If* your string actually contained `?`s, then no, they would not magically return to their original characters. Your string, however, most likely does not contain `?`s, it's the non-Unicode debugger that is unable to display them in its non-Unicode tooltip, like Panagiotis Kanavos [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845933/vba-combining-two-non-ascii-languages-in-userform#comment116421461_65845933). If you want to examine the true contents of the string, output it via a channel that is also Unicode, e.g. do `ActiveCell.Value = Str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve the problem and here are the conclusions:

1. The question marks that appear do not affect the text that will be send to SQL SERVER, even if it is concatenated with other text to a new variable.
2. The problem was probably within the stored procedure, although I had a very hard time checking it out there, because it's a long and very complex code that handles a lot of things, but my feeling that the problem is in the "dynamic SQL" that executes the SQL string I send there.
3. I solved the problem by sending a SQL string cleanly without the stored procedure.